# Does it make sense to talk about the speed of sound at some pressure?

Tags: pressure, acoustics

Physically speaking, does it make sense to talk about the "speed of sound at some pressure"? Is this a coherent concept?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound): “The speed of sound in an ideal gas depends only on its temperature and composition. The speed has a weak dependence on frequency and pressure in ordinary air, deviating slightly from ideal behavior.“

Comment: @G.Smith Hmm, so would sound have a greater dependence on a denser medium ?

Comment: The Wikipedia article talks about that as well.

Comment: @G.Smith Ahh, yes, got it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Dependence_on_the_properties_of_the_medium Thanks!

Comment: The speed of sound is given by $C_{s}^{2} = \tfrac{ \partial P }{ \partial \rho }$, where $P$ is the pressure and $\rho$ is the mass density.  So it's more of how changes in the pressure depends upon density than just the pressure.